# ACM ICPC - Exactly K bridges in Graph

Tags: c++, graph, graph-theory, combinatorics, graph-traversal

I'm practicing for ACM ICPC and I came on this problem from 2017 ACM ICPC Arab Regionals:

First, let’s define an undirected connected labeled graph, it’s a graph with N nodes with a unique label
for each node and some edges, there’s no specific direction for each edge, also duplicate edges and edges
from a node to itself aren’t allowed, and from any node you can reach any other node.
A bridge in such graph is an edge that if we remove it, the graph will be disconnected (there will
exist nodes which aren’t reachable from each other).
In this problem you are given N and K, and your task is to count the number of different undirected
connected labeled graphs with exactly N nodes and K bridges. Since that number can be huge, print
it modulo M.
An edge is defined using the labels of the nodes it connects, for example we can say (X, Y ) is an
edge between X and Y , also (Y, X) is considered the same edge (since it’s undirected). Two graphs are
considered different, if there’s an edge which exists in one of them but not the other.

Input:

Your program will be tested on one or more test cases. The first line of the input will be a single integer
T (1 ≤ T ≤ 100) representing the number of test cases. Followed by T test cases.
Each test case will be just one line containing 3 integers separated by a space, N (1 ≤ N ≤ 50), K
(0 ≤ K < N) and M (1 ≤ M ≤ 10^9), which are the numbers described in the statement. It’s guaranteed that N will not be more than 25 in 95% of the test cases

Output:

For each test case, print a single line with the number of graphs as described above modulo M.

```
Sample Input:
4
3 2 10
3 0 10
6 3 10000 
6 3 1000

Sample Output
3
1
2160
160
```

I tried to come up with some formula that would work for all N and K but I had no success. Can someone tell me what should I do to solve it, because I couldn't find any editorial? Thanks in advance

Comment: Same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779612/undirected-labeled-connected-graph-with-k-bridges